# What are the model configuration parameters in tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-recognition

In the Config file there are some parameters which I don't understand properly . I will mention them here.

**first_stage_features_stride** - Is this the ration of **input/output** ?

**height_stride** (In the first_stage_anchor_generator) - What is this ?